# how to remove magento wishlist page title for custom theme

Tags: magento-1.9

i already try to edit wishlist.xml page.

            
                
                    My Wishlist
                
        
please suggest me .
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Copy this file to your custom theme:

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/view.phtml

And remove from there everything you like.

Title is adding here:

```
<h1><?php echo $this->getTitle(); ?></h1>
```

Comment: <title>My Wishlist</title>  this is page title . i want to edit this.

Comment: I saw 2 days ago such question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508231/how-can-i-change-my-wishlist-page-title-in-magento

Comment: this link also fail in my case., i don't know what happen.

Comment: Its workable solution. Check why its not working for you. Check if your layout/local.xml file is working.